# for loops in python returning last condition

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to Python and I'm practicing working with data frames.

I have a `data` frame with a column that consists of months in string format `("OCTOBER","NOVEMBER" etc)`.

I wrote a simple `for` loop in order to to get a new column with numeric values.

```
 for x in range(0,39053):
    if data.iloc[x,25]=="DEC":
     data["month"]=12
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="OCT":
       data["month"]=10
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="JUL":
       data["month"]=7   
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="SEP":
       data["month"]=9 
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="AUG":
       data["month"]=8   
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="JUN":
       data["month"]=8 
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="MAY":
       data["month"]=5 
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="APR":
       data["month"]=4 
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="MAR":
       data["month"]=3 
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="FEB":
       data["month"]=2     
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="JAN":
       data["month"]=1     
    elif data.iloc[x,25]=="NOV":
       data["month"]=11
```

For some reason, I keep getting all of the values equal to `11` even though I know there are entries for all the months.

For example, if I run the following code it returns `True` for the value `"DEC"`

```
data.iloc[45,25]=="DEC"
```

The way that I understand the code I wrote, is that for each row you take the value of the variable in column 25 (which is the month) and then you take the numeric value corresponding with the first time the condition is met.

Once the condition is met you stop looking and move to the next row.

Any idea where I made a mistake here?

Comment: can you provide data for us? without knowing what `data` looks like we can't do jack

Comment: don't do those horrible statements. Use a dictionary to convert the months to values, and your problem will probably go away (and the code will be much much faster)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: The problem is that you are assigning to the same key in `data` every time, and presumably `data.iloc[39052, 25]` is `'NOV'`, which overwrites all previous assignments. You need to assign to `data['month'][x]` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

to answer this question, we have to understand what is the datatype of data.iloc and how are you accessing data.iloc[45,25]? - if iloc is a dictionary with the tuple (45,25) as key then access data.iloc[(x,25)].